# Changing bounds on double integral

Tags: integration

I have the following integral and with the following substitutions that I made:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$

$u=x^2, v=y^2$

$du = 2xdx, dv = 2ydy$

Which led me to

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}\sqrt{u+v}\,du\,dv$$

However this seems wrong to me. Don't I have to update $a,b,c,d$ now that I've made the substitution over $x$ and $y$? How do I know what to change them to? Do I square everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this, $u=x^2$ when $x=a$ then $u=a^2$, when $x=b$ then $u=b^2$. Similarly,$v=y^2$ when $y=c$ then $v=c^2$, when $y=d$ then $v=d^2$.

Comment: It's not a question of square, its a question of change of variable, understand like this, if your function of $x$ varies on $[a,b]$ then you change to $u=x^2$ makes your interval of definition change, now your interval is [a^2,b^2], do you see?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: In your case, $\int_c^d(\text{bla bla})\, dx$ means that you're integrating from $x=c$ to $x=d$. After you've made your substitution, you want this to be unchanged. Only now you have to write it as integrating from $u=?$ to $u=?$.